# Simple way to pick first variable that exists

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to input a couple variables and return the first one that exists?

For example, either `$_POST['a'][$field]` or `$_POST['b'][$field]` will exist – only one or the other, never both.

I want to assign whichever variable exists to a variable.

I was hoping for a syntax like this:

```
$field = $_POST['a'][$field] or $_POST['b'][$field];
```

but this will only return `$_POST['a'][$field]` (if it exists) or `NULL`

And I do know that I can do:

```
if(isset($_POST['a'][$field])){
    $field = $_POST['a'][$field];
} else {
    $field = $_POST['b'][$field];
}
```

but I was wondering if there is something more simple that I am not thinking of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). It can be chained it as many times as you need, so you can also have a default value if neither is selected.

```
$field = $_POST['a'][$field] ?? $_POST['b'][$field] ?? "default";
```

Comment: Was about to ask if this is better than ternary operator of `?:` but I see the page you linked shows the equivalent. Thank you!

Comment: No point in using the ternary any longer. (For this use case!)